# Python: Dynamic Importation From Discovered Files with a Frozen Program

Tags: python, python-import, game-development

My current (Python) program is designed such that it has a "core", which implements the base functionality of the thing, and (potentially) multiple "content-sets" that provide specific elements.

Note that these "content-sets" include code, providing functionality specific to them. Further, note that that classes defined within a "content-set" may derive from classes in the "core".

(To be specific, the program is a game, with the "content-sets" providing individual "adventures", including locations, enemies, etc.--hence their including code of their own.)

At startup, the "core" then scans the "content" directory, looking for "content-sets", lists any that it finds, and makes them available for use.

During development, all of this works nicely!

However, when I attempt to build a distributable--which freezes the "core" into an executable--it all falls apart, I fear. :/

(If I'm using the term "freezes" there correctly--what I mean is that it takes the Python scripts and makes an executable of them. For the sake of clarity, this is also what I mean below when I refer to "frozen" things.)

Specifically, it seems that the Python scripts within a "content-set" cannot perceive the classes defined within the frozen "core", causing the thing to crash. (I don't know whether this is because they have no access to those classes at all, or whether the frozen versions of the classes have different locations to the non-frozen versions--or something else that I'm not thinking of.)

Perhaps relevantly, I would ideally like to have the "content-sets" be bundled up in some way, rather than distributed simply as directories. (Thus far I've been employing an archive format related to the game-engine that I use, which allows files to be mounted as though present on disk--but I am worried that simply having the Python files in there might affect performance.)

Does anyone have any ideas as to how this might be made to work...?

**As to what I've tried, what I expected, and what actually happened:**

I tried running the program as during development, with the current "content-set" in place and attempting to sub-class from the frozen "core".

I was expecting that this would work as with an non-frozen "core".

What actually happened was that the program crashed with an exception indicating that it couldn't find the parent-class in question.

(As a workaround, for the moment I'm just statically importing my current "content-set". This works, but doesn't allow for other "content-sets" in the future.)

**As to the request in the comments for code**
I suppose that something like this might work:

In the "core" files:

"Cat.py"
`

```
class Cat():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = "meow"
```

"Main.py"
`

```
import os, importlib

for f in os.scandir("."):
    if f.name == "Kitten.py":
        module = importlib.import_module(f.name[:-3])
        if module is not None:
            kitty = module.Kitten()
            print (kitty.cuteness)
```

And then, in the "content-set":
"Kitten.py"
`

```
from Cat import Cat

class Kitten(Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        Cat.__init__(self)
        self.cuteness = "intense"
```

"Main.py" and "Cat.py" would then be frozen into an executable, while "Kitten.py" would be external--and attempting to sub-class the class defined in the frozen "Cat.py".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the original post with a simple code-example. (Naturally it doesn't include a frozen executable, but hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to do.)